# How to update string in python in existing data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below command output:

```
data = """
abcd11  11  
abcd12  12  
abcd13  13
abcd21  14
abcd22  15
abcd23  16
abcd101  17
abcd102  18
abcd103  19

... so on
abcd501  1
abcd502  2

"""
```

## Condition1 Numbers (As per data it is string) range must be between 1 to 255, that is not exceed 255,

Code:

```
#Check abcd401, abcd402, abcd403   

check = set()
for line in data.split("\n"):
    if len(line.split()) > 1:
        line = line.strip()
        check.add(line.split()[0])

if not "abcd401" in check and not "abcd402" in check and not "abcd402" in check:
            print "Not exist"
else:
    print "Its already exist. Program exit"
    sys.exit()
```

Now Need to assign a Number to abcd401, abcd402, abcd403

Number between 1 to 255.

I can always assign abcd401 = 1, abcd402 = 2, abcd403 = 3, but i need to fill 1-255, then starts 1-255, and so on Please help.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear as to what you are trying to do. The title says that you need to select numbers but the description mentions that you are trying to update. Furthermore, it is a string that you are trying to manipulate rather than a "number". Have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question. Please update your question for clarity.

Comment: @abc As far as I understood- you can use a counter variable initialized to 1 and assign a check to it at the time of adding number to abcdxxx- if it is exceeds 255 then reset the counter variable to 1 else assign the number and then increment by1.

Comment: Let me select 1-255 random select. Now I have only solution. since cannot have any logic to apply. counter not feasible. because all the times results will be 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

- I am trying to solve adding the line if not exist in the data (`data`
  is multiline string input content).
- This can be done using pandas
  with the easy way, also solution will scales if you use pandas.
- I did
  not focus on the randomizing the number assigned to each line, I just
  cycling from 1 to 255 and once idx is reached I am starting from 1
  again. :)
- this part you can take care...

My quick solution is:

```
import cStringIO as io
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle

text_data = """abcd11  11  
abcd12  12  
abcd13  13
abcd21  14
abcd22  15
abcd23  16
abcd101  17
abcd102  18
abcd103  19
abcd501  1
abcd502  2"""


def get_next_id():
    cyc = cycle(range(1,256))
    for i in cyc:
        yield i
next_id = get_next_id()


def load_data():
    content = io.StringIO(text_data)
    df = pd.read_csv(content, header=None, sep="\s+", names=["txt", "num"])
    print "Content is loaded to pandas dataframe\n", df
    return df


def add_line_to_df(txt, df):
    idx = next_id.next()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([[txt, idx]], columns=["txt", "num"])
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = df2.iloc[0]
    #print df #res_df
    return df # res_df


def insert_valid_line(line, df):
    if line in pd.Series(df["txt"]).values:
        print "{}: already existed.".format(line)
    else:
        print "{}: adding to existing df.".format(line)
        add_line_to_df(line, df)


def main():
    df = load_data()
    new_texts = ["abcd501", "abcd502", "abcd402", "abcd403"]

    for txt in new_texts:
        print "-" * 20
        insert_valid_line(txt, df)

    print "-" * 20
    print df
    #In this place df is holding all the data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output looks like this...:

```
Content is loaded to pandas dataframe
        txt  num
0    abcd11   11
1    abcd12   12
2    abcd13   13
3    abcd21   14
4    abcd22   15
5    abcd23   16
6   abcd101   17
7   abcd102   18
8   abcd103   19
9   abcd501    1
10  abcd502    2
--------------------
abcd501: already existed.
--------------------
abcd502: already existed.
--------------------
abcd402: adding to existing df.
--------------------
abcd403: adding to existing df.
--------------------
        txt  num
0    abcd11   11
1    abcd12   12
2    abcd13   13
3    abcd21   14
4    abcd22   15
5    abcd23   16
6   abcd101   17
7   abcd102   18
8   abcd103   19
9   abcd501    1
10  abcd502    2
11  abcd402    1
12  abcd403    2
```